# Deserializing a simple JSON array

Tags: json, vb.net, deserialization

This should be straightforward but I can't figure it out.

I have a simple JSON array:
[{"carId":1,"status":"Active","inventory":"3"},
{"carId":2,"status":"Active","inventory":"5"}]

I have my JSON classes:

```
Friend Class carModel
    Public Property carId As String
    Public Property status As String
    Public Property inventory As String
End Class

Friend Class carWrapper
    Friend arrcarModel() As carModel
End Class
```

And I have the following code:

```
Dim currentWrapper = DeserializeObject(Of List(Of carWrapper))(strJSON)

If currentWrapper.Count > 0 Then
    For i As Integer = 0 To RXWrapper.Count - 1
        Dim carItem = currentWrapper(i).arrcarModel
    Next
End If
```

Although the code does indeed result with currentWrapper.Count = 2, currentWrapper(i).arrcarModel always winds up equal to Nothing.

What am I not doing correctly?  Is there a more standard approach to deserializing a JSON array?

Thanks!

Comment: There's no Root object there. You have just an array of `carModel` objects. I.e., you don't need `carWrapper`.

Comment: Hey Jimi.  You're right that there's a root object missing.  Thanks for that.  But I don't know how to process a JSON array (as opposed to a simple JSON string) without a wrapper...

Comment: `Dim cardModels = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of CarModel))(strJSON)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio has a cool feature called Paste JSON as Classes that can be found under Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON as Classes. If you were to do this, then you would get something that looks like the following:

```vb
Public Class Rootobject
    Public Property Property1() As Class1
End Class

Public Class Class1
    Public Property carId As Integer
    Public Property status As String
    Public Property inventory As String
End Class
```

Personally, I would clean up the class a little bit by doing some renaming and using decorators. For example:

```vb
Public Class CarWrapper

    Public Property CarModels As IEnumerable(Of CarModel)

End Class

Public Class CarModel

    <JsonProperty("carId")>
    Public Property CarId As Integer

    <JsonProperty("status")>
    Public Property Status As String

    <JsonProperty("inventory")>
    Public Property Inventory As String

End Class
```

Now what you would do is create a new instance of the `CarWrapper` class and set the `CarModels` property equal to the deserialization of the JSON:

```vb
Dim json = <json>
            [
                {
                    "carId": 1,
                    "status": "Active",
                    "inventory": "3"
                },
                {
                    "carId": 2,
                    "status": "Active",
                    "inventory": "5"
                }
            ]
            </json>.Value
Dim wrapper = New CarWrapper() With {
    .CarModels = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of CarModel())(json)
}

For Each model In wrapper.CarModels
    Console.WriteLine("Id: {0}, Status: {1}, Inventory: {2}", model.CarId, model.Status, model.Inventory)
Next
```

Comment: Hey David.  This works perfectly!  Thanks for taking the time to lay out the details of the solution.  Greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: @Mike - No problem!